# Preventing compilation of a function (or part of) based on template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Given a class such as

```
template<typename T = void>
class Foo
{
    void Baz()
    {
        // Do something regardless of specialization
        /* Do stuff if the template was specified (i.e. if not void) */
        /* This cannot be handled with an if statement because it will not compile if T == void */    
    }

   /* Rest if class */
}
```

How can I let the compiler know that it shouldn't compile a section of the function if `T == void`? I originally tried doing this with just an `if` statement but it won't compile as that section of code uses the `<<` operator with a variable of type `T` (which clearly is wrong if `T == void`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use class template parameters to get SFINAE for member functions.

You can use a *dummy* template argument for member function like following :

```
template<typename T = void>
class Foo
{
   public:
   template <typename Dummy = char>
    void Baz(typename std::enable_if< !std::is_same<T ,void>::value, 
                                 Dummy>::type * = 0)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

<kbd>[*`See Here`*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dff507700e7cafda)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks :) I just realised I pass the function `Baz` two arguments (both `unsigned int`). How do I include those in the example you give? I tried just seeing if putting them at the start/end of the argument list worked but I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use template specialization like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void BazHelper(){
    // Do something regardless of specialization
    /* Do stuff if the template was specified (i.e. if not void) */
    std::cout << "Not void code\n";
}

template <>
void BazHelper<void>(){
    // Do something regardless of specialization
    /* Do NOT do stuff if the template was specified (i.e. if not void) */
    std::cout << "void code\n";
}

template<typename T = void>
struct Foo{
    void Baz()
    {
        // Do something regardless of specialization
        BazHelper<T>();
        /* Do stuff if the template was specified (i.e. if not void) */
        /* This cannot be handled with an if statement because it will not compile if T == void */
    }

    /* Rest if class */
};

int main(){
    Foo<> vf;
    vf.Baz();
    Foo<double> df;
    df.Baz();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to go with the other approach given for now but I'll keep this one in mind

Answer (score 0):

Use a macro to achieve a usage like a annotation that is bases on member function template.

```
#define enable_if(...) template<typename _T = int, std::enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__::value, _T> = {}, __VA_ARGS__* = nullptr>

// #define enable_if(...) template<typename _T = int, typename = typename std::enable_if<__VA_ARGS__, _T>::type>  // deprecated
// #define enable_if(...) template<typename _T = int, typename std::enable_if<__VA_ARGS__, _T>::type = 0>         // deprecated
```

`__VA_ARGS__` should be a class with static bool member variable named value.

Reusing `__VA_ARGS__* = nullptr` as an unqiue template Signature, so we don't declare same member function templates in one class.
Otherwise, `enable_if(condition)` gets `enable_if_t<false>` and `enable_if_t<true>` two versions only, so that we could use the macro no more than twice for functions with same names, and make sure `condition` will never genarate two `enable_if_t<false/true>` when use the macro twice (just like the deprecated ones).

```
template <typename T> 
class Foo
{
public:
    enable_if(std::is_same<T, void>)
    void Baz(int k){ ... }

    enable_if(std::is_same<T, int>)
    void Baz(int k){ ... }

    enable_if(std::is_same<T, std::string>)
    void Baz(int k){ ... }

};
```

use as follow ：

```
Foo<void> x;
x.Baz(3);

Foo<int> y;
y.Baz(3);

Foo<std::string> z;
z.Baz(3);

Foo<char> a;
//! a.Baz(3);
```